# Is there a disassembler with modification and reassembly capabilities for a 32-bit executable?

Tags: c++, assembly, executable, decompiler, disassembly

I have a class project where we need to take a 32-bit executable written in C++ and disassemble it and modify the assembly code and then reassemble it. We're supposed to do things like hardcode cheats into the game.

I've been searching for hours and I can't find any software that will do this. I've looked at Ollydbg and spent about two hours with it and couldn't really figure out how to get it to work. I utilized Cheat Engine and that actually worked out really well for me - I was able to isolate the code modifying the addresses I cared about and replace it with code to have a favorable impact on the game, but as far as I can tell Cheat Engine has no ability to recompile the modified code.

This is a fairly lower level Computer Science class so please take into account my ability level when making suggestions but if there is any software out there or alternative ways that will allow me to do this I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking about software are off topic on SO, but yours seems interesting and I haven't seen such a question before.

Comment: Take a look at the free version of IDA Pro from Hexrays.

Comment: [Agner Fog's `objconv` disassembler](http://agner.org/optimize) outputs NASM, MASM, or GNU assembly, at your option.  It won't re-assemble into byte-for-byte identical code, though.  e.g. an instruction with an `imm32` that could have used an `imm8` will end up with an `imm8`.  NASM / YASM syntax does support stuff like `add eax, dword 1` to emit `add eax, imm32`, but objconv doesn't do that.  There isn't syntax for choosing between the `add r/m32, imm32` encoding or the special opcode for add-imm32-to-eax (that makes a 5 byte insn including the immediate, like a mov-immediate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned OllyDBG and Cheat Engine I'm going to assume you're using Windows.

First, you can use OllyDBG to save a file, but for some reason I can't find this option in OllyDBG 2, only in older versions (like 1.10). You can right-click on the code window and then `copy to executable > all modifications`, A new window will open, right-click on the new window and then choose `save file`.

An alternative that I really like is [x64dbg](https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg/releases). it's an open source debugger/disassembler and has an option to save changes via "Patches".

Another option is to apply the changes via an hex editor, which allows you to modify any file (including executables) in a binary format. It is, of course, a bit harder to do since you need to translate your changes to op-codes manually, but if your changes are not too big or only consisting of modifying some constants it can be a faster and easier solution. There are a lot of hex editors out there but my favorite is [XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm).

What I personally like to do is to modify the memory via code using Windows API's [WriteProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ReadProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx) since it allows you to do this things dynamically.

Comment: I can use Cheat Engine to modify the code on the fly and see what my modifications to the code in assembly do, and then it will automatically generate the OPCODES for me from the code I wrote. Then I can just find the corresponding original hex with the editor and change that! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Koronakesh Happy to help :) What hex editor did you end up using?

Comment: HxD is the one I found.